# rbash with sftp

Tags: ssh, sftp, bash

I would like to know if it's possible to have sftp access with rbash enabled on the users, if not Is there any alternative to rbash?

Thanks

Comment: Try it, see what happens, and if you run into any errors let us know and we'll try to help out.

Comment: I tried but Its not allowing it, I found an alternative here: http://wiki.tony-su.com/How_to_restrict_sftp_user_in_Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

from what i've learned - rbash won't work with sftp.  a shell, scp, yes.  sftp; no.

probably the best alternative is rssh.  it allows for chrooting and specific access to any/all of:  scp, sftp, cvs, rdist, and rsync.

the trickiest part is creating per-user chroot "jails", as each jail must contain everything (directory structure and shared libraries) to the binaries you allow to be run (e.g. sftp which usually resides in /usr/libexec/sftp-server).  but you can even use "hard links" among the several jails to save the space of having a copy of every shared library in each jail.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, but it is worth putting correct answer here: 
in order to allow SFTP working with SSH, one need to change the Subsystem in sshd_config:

```
~$ grep Subsystem /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```